# Turtlebot3 Burger RemotePC to Raspberry Pi 4 Teleop Not Moving

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ros

I am trying to run roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot_teleop_key.launch on a remote PC, but turtlebot3 is not moving. I've tried swapping the ROS_MASTER_URI and roscore to the pi and that returns the correct publisher and subscriber, but the bot will still not move.

The setup:

REMOTE_PC:

ROS_MASTER_URI={IP_OF_REMOTE_PC}

ROS_HOSTNAME={IP_OF_REMOTE_PC}

PI:

ROS_MASTER_URI={IP_OF_REMOTE_PC}

ROS_HOSTNAME={IP_ADDRESS_OF_PI}

commands:

RUN ROSCORE ON REMOTE PC

RUN ROSLAUNCH TURTLEBOT3_BRINGUP TURTLEBOT3_ROBOT.LAUNCH ON PI

RUN ROSLAUNCH TURTLEBOT3_TELEOP TURTLEBOT3_TELEOP_KEY.LAUNCH ON REMOTE PC

Comment: There isn't enough information to really answer the question here. Are you getting any errors? Are you seeing data across the topics? etc

Comment: No errors, but I fail test 5.6 of this [guide](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup). That test is publishing a string from the remote PC that can be read on the subscriber's terminal(Turtlebot3). I verified the ROS_HOSTNAME as the step said, but the input seems to be correct per ifconfig

Comment: Can you ping each computer from the other?

Comment: I was able to ping them, but receiving data via publisher and subscribers was only working in one direction.
Solved! What ended up needing to be changed was change ROS_HOST and ROS_MASTER_URI. I had entered the ip address, but changing them to hostname.local fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! What ended up needing to be changed was change ROS_HOST and ROS_MASTER_URI. I had entered the ip address, but changing them to hostname.local fixed it.

This means that
remote pc
find hostname with hostname command in terminal

ROS_HOST = remote_pc_hostname.local

ROS_MASTER_URI=whatever is runnning roscore_hostname.local

rpi

ROS_HOST = rpi_hostname.local

ROS_MASTER_URI=whatever is runnning roscore_hostname.local